# Using the Plot function with the Manipulate function

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Can anyone explain why the below code does not produce a plot?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_, a_] = a - x^2;
Solve[f[x, a] == x, x]

Manipulate[ Plot[{f[x, a], x}, {a, -2, 2}], {a, 1, 20, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Partly because using `Solve` doesn't set the value of `x`, so you are trying to plot something that has the parameter `x` in it with no value plugged in for `x`. You also have some scoping problems, I think, where the `a`'s aren't actually the same. It's actually pretty unclear what you're actually trying to do here. Can you add some explanations to your post?

Comment: You should plot for `x`, not for `a`. Change to : `Manipulate[ Plot[{f[x, a], x}, {x, -2, 2}], {a, 1, 20, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_, a_] = a - x^2;
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[x, a], x},
  {x, -5, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{x, f[x, a]} /. # & /@ Solve[f[x, a] == x, x]]}
  ],
 {a, 1, 20, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: OP here. I had to log into the correct account. Sorry for the confusion in my post. I'm not familiar with how the end of the `Epilog` line works. That is, what does ` /. # & /@ ` do? I am inferring that this places a red point where I have a fixed point, but i'm still curious. And thank you for the help!

Comment: `/.` is shorthand Infix notation for `ReplaceAll`. `/@` is Infix notation for `Map`. `#` is `Slot[1]` which is used for defining a pure function with `&` is the short-hand for `Function`. You can look up all of these in the documentation.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the information. Since I am not in the original account I posted in (my mistake), I supposed i'll just say: **POST RESOLVED** ?Maybe I can ask a moderator to accept this post?

Comment: @Ozera. You should be able to merge accounts, perhaps by contacting a moderator.

Comment: @Ozera, please see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for help with merging your accounts.

Answer (score 2):

With a few bells and whistles.

```
Clear[f]

f[x_, a_] = a - x^2;
soln[x_, a_] = Solve[f[x, a] == x, x];

Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Plot[{f[x, a], x}, {x, -2, 2},
    Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5],
      Point[{x, f[x, a]} /. soln[x, a]]},
    ImageSize -> 360,
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{f[x, a], x}, {.7, .2}]], 
   StringForm["\nx = ``", Or @@ (x /. soln[x, a])]},
  Alignment -> Center],
 {{a, 0}, -0.25, 2, .05,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]